# Fs.writeFile writes [Object, Object] instead of writing the actual response

Tags: node.js, api, get, axios

I am trying to write the response from this API call on message.txt, but I only get [Object Object] while the console.log shows me the exact content of the response. Where am I wrong? Thank you.

```
axios({
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "https://twelvedata.p.rapidapi.com/bbands",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "twelvedata.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "hidden",
      "useQueryString": true
    },
    "params": {
      "sd": "2",
      "outputsize": "120",
      "series_type": "close",
      "ma_type": "SMA",
      "time_period": "20",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "interval": "5min",
      "apikey": "hidden"
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    fs.writeFile('message.txt', res, (err) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
      }
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that [object Object] is being written to the file is that this is the result of the default Object.toString() call, which fs.writeFile is using to serialize the object to a string.

The simplest way to get the desired behaviour will be to convert the Object to a string yourself before writing to the file. [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is the most straightforward way to do this.

For example:

```
axios({
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "https://twelvedata.p.rapidapi.com/bbands",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "twelvedata.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "hidden",
      "useQueryString": true
    },
    "params": {
      "sd": "2",
      "outputsize": "120",
      "series_type": "close",
      "ma_type": "SMA",
      "time_period": "20",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "interval": "5min",
      "apikey": "hidden"
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // Serialize the res object using JSON.stringify
    fs.writeFile('message.txt', JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 4), (err) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
      }
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I am not sure I understood well why it works. Is that:
1- first axios automatically parse data from JSON to JS, 
2- Fs.writeFile takes that parsed JS object and performs Object.toString() on it, but doing so it will only write [object, Object]
3- while if Fs.writeFile performs Object.toString() on JSON data it will write it fully?
Did I get anything right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, Axios will parse the data to an object, although the response body itself will be in response.data, so we might actually want to do JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 4) rather than saving the whole response to the file (a lot of extra data we probably don't need). 2. I think is the behaviour we'll see, though for 3, the JSON.stringify call will convert the object to a string, so fs.writeFile can write directly to the file without needing to call .toString (since it's a string already).

Comment: No problem, glad to help!